# Javascript regex URL matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this so far:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) 
{
    var title = tab.title;
    var btn = '<a href="' + tab.url + '" onclick="save(\'' + title + '\');"> ' + title + '</a>';
        
    if(tab.url.match('/http:\/\/www.example.com\/version.php/i')) 
    {
        document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = '<p>' + btn + '</p>';
    }
});
```

Basically it should match the domain within this:

```
http://www.example.com/version.php?*
```

Anything that matches that even when it includes something like version.php?ver=1, etc

When I used the code above of mine, it doesn't display anything, but when I remove the if statement, it's fine but it shows on other pages which it shouldn't **only** on the matched URL.

**EDIT:**

```
if(tab.url.match(/http:\/\/www.example.com\/version.php/i)) 
{
    document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = '<p>' + btn + '</p>';
}
```

Doesn't even work somehow...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(tab.url.match(/http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/version\.php/i)) 
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes. Opera DargonFly gives me:

```
>>> 'http://www.example.com/version.php'.match(/^http:\/\/www\.example.com\/version\.php/i) 
[object Array]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the RegExp object, but you're not matching it against anything. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp) for how to use it (by the way, the syntax is also wrong, it's either /expression/modifiers or RegExp(expression, modifiers)).

Answer (score 0):

`match()` should take a `RegExp` object as argument, not a string. You could probably just remove the single quotes `''` from around the expression to make it work. For future reference, you should also escape the periods `.` in the expression (as it is they will match *any* single character), and insert a `^` in the beginning to only allow this match in the beginning of the URL.