# javascript regex match correct url, with .com or any other domain at the end

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if a Javascript string is an url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-an-url)

I am not very familiar with RegEx so it would be great if you could help me solve this problem.

I need a JS function that will:

1. Check for the string (textarea input) if it has any url.
2. If yes - search for the first url found and return array(true,url)
3. If no - return array(false,"")

The problem I am having is this pattern that validates input.

```
function _is_url(url) {
    var pattern = /(((ht|f)tps?\:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5})(:[\d]{1,5})?))\S+/i;
    var result = new Array();
    var testing = pattern.test(url);
    if(testing) {
        var newurl = url.match(pattern);
        result[0] = true;
        result[1] = newurl[0];
        console.log(result[1]);
    }
    else {
        result[0] = false;
        result[1] = "";
    }

    return result;
}
```

With this pattern, testing == true even if the url is **http://www.youtube** which is not a valid url.

What I need is to check the full url: **http://www.youtube.com** and any other url.

Comment: If you want to match invalid urls, it becomes simply `/[a-z]+://[^s]+/`.

Comment: Why do you think `.youtube` might not be a valid TLD? If Google had enought money, they might register it :-)

Comment: @Bergi Try it and  you will see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `\S+` after your expression to exclude `www.youtube`, and add a word boundary `\b`. Also `{1}` after the first letter can be omitted.

Comment: In the console.log(result[1]), im still getting 

http://www.yo
http://www.you
http://www.yout
...
http://www.youtube.com

Comment: `/(((ht|f)tps?\:\/\/)?([a-zA-Z]([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5})(:[\d]{1,5})?))\b/i` works for me. Please show me a demo with your inputs. Btw, `.yo` or `.you` might really be valid TLDs.

Comment: you missunderstood my question or I didn't write it good.

The thing is that ht tp://youtu is not a valid url while ht tp://youtu.be IS a valid url. I want to check only for valid url's which htt p://face or htt p://goo is not

Comment: Your pattern works great if we're writting htt p://domain without WWW but if I write htt p://www.you - it will say it's true. So the only thing is missing checking for www and ignoring it as a domain name.

Comment: I am so close, only thing left is making this (www.?) optional:
/(((ht|f)tps?\:\/\/)?(www.?)([a-zA-Z]([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5})(:[\d]{1,5})?))\b/i

Comment: `www.you` is a uncommon, but valid domain. Please tell us before what you want :-) You should be able to ignore `www` parts by inserting `(www\.)?(?!www\.)` after the protocol part.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u7PNn/4/ Please take a look

Comment: Taken a look, nothing happens. A self-executing example would have been better :-) No really, I tried the pastes you provided, and they work with my pattern.