# Validate url using regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a string to validate if it is a valid url or not. 
I have googled it, I could only found the solution if url contains `http or https`

I want to make the url as `valid` even if it does not contain http infront of its domain name `example -> www.google.com`

These are some of the urls I have tried and they did work.

```
http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-an-url
```

But they validate it as true even when I give `h/www.stackoverflow.com` which is not a valid  url
also `/www.stackoverflow.com` validates to true

They are not the valid urls. Can anyone help me writing the regular expression.
I wanted to write this regular exp on my own
but I am unable to find good tutorials on regexp. I could barely write expressions such as containing a character, a litle small ones.

I believe its the area Iam little weak I want to practise some regular expressions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kindly help me in validating this url.

**Update**

```
 ((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-_]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w_]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)
```

This is the regexp Iam currently using

I kindly request you to make a js fiddle and that makes h/www.stackoverflow.com to false. Sorry but none of the answers did not work.

Comment: Please post your regex which you got now.

Comment: So make the first part optional...

Comment: @Xatenev just updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this (works on urls that starts with www.)

```
function ValidURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)+[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,5}(?:(?:\/|#|\?)[^\s]*)?','i');
  if(!pattern.test(str)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?:https?://|www.)+[a-z0-9-.]+.[a-z]{2,5}(?:(?:/|#|?)[^s]*)?/: Nothing to repeat

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternate method for matching URLs if they are strings.

```
var x;
try {
    var t = new URL( yourStringHere );
    x = true;
}
catch( e ) {
    x = false;
}
```