# Regex - Matching Only Part of the String

Tags: javascript, regex

Its part of an exercise and the task is:

1. If the first arg is only the url, then return the url + the second arg (which is a id number) //that works in my code
2. If the first arg (url) includes already the id-then exchange that Id with the second arg(Id) -for example `http://www.google.com?ID=111` becomes `http://www.google.com?ID=222`

My code is wrong, happy about suggestions!

```
var first = "http://www.google.com?ID=111";
var second = "ID=222";

function searching(){
    var update="";
    if (arguments[0]==/^\w+@\w+\.com$/i){
        return arguments[0]+"?"+arguments[1];
    }
    else {
        update=arguments[0].match(/(\w+@\w+\.com) \?\w+\d/i);
    }
    return update + "?" +arguments[1]; 
}

searching(first, second);
```

Comment: Your regexp has a space before `\?`, but there's no space in the URL.

Comment: Why are you calling the function with arguments when it has no parameters?

Comment: You are explicitly scanning for .com domains. Is that part of the exercise?

Comment: Why does your regexp have `@` in it? There's no `@` in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just compare a string to a regex with `==`. Basically your choices are [match, test, replace, and split](http://james.padolsey.com/general/regular-expressions-in-javascript). your regex btw has a `\w` when you wanted just a `w`, should be: `/www\.\w+\.com$/i` - I just shortened it even further. there's a million shades of regex validation when it comes to [testing for valid URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5717133/244811) in javascript. Generally, I think, you should just construct a "good enough" regex for your use case: here we just care if the query param is there, or not:

```
var first = "http://www.google.com?ID=111";
var second = "ID=222";
function searching(){
    var update="";
    if (/^.*\.com$/i.test(arguments[0])){ 
        //pattern just checks end of string to see if query param is present.
        return arguments[0]+"?"+arguments[1];
    }
    else {
        update=arguments[0].replace(/ID=\d+/, second); //
    }
    return update;
}
searching(first, second);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain if (/^.*\.com$/.test(arguments[0])){   and why (what I wrote):  if (arguments[0]==/^\www.\w+\.com$/i){ is wrong?

Comment: Okay so I changed it to if (arguments[0].match(/^www\.\w+\.com$/i)){
update=arguments[0]+"?"+arguments[1];
}  but thats wrong too?!

Comment: that's wrong. `match` return a match object, and would not perform the `replace` that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check for the `?` and if the first argument contain the sign '?' then get the first part (url) using `.split('?')[0]` and add second argument `arguments[1]`, else just add the second argument directely to the first argument (url) :

```
function searching()
{
    if (arguments[0].indexOf('?')!=-1)
        return arguments[0].split('?')[0]+"?"+arguments[1];
    else 
        return arguments[0]+"?"+arguments[1];
}
```

Hope this helps.