# XSS safe img src insertion

Tags: javascript, html

How do you safely push a user influenced url to the DOM, namely to the `src` attribute of an `img`?

`<img>` won't execute anything else than a valid img and scripting in svg is limited. Casual `onload` tricks won't work aswell because the input is quoted. Is this enough to ensure a safe DOM insertion via img?

The snippet is simplified, there are checks for `url` being a valid url.

Edit: something like `http://foo" onerror="alert(&apos;XSS&apos;)" "` **is not** a valid url, see here: http://foo" onerror="alert('XSS')" ". You can assume that `url` is for sure a valid url. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters,  [Check if a Javascript string is a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url) and https://jsfiddle.net/mppkgd7u/

```js
var user = 'random/url/path'; // any kind of user generated string
var url = 'http://' + user; // guaranteed to be url
document.getElementById('view').innerHtml = '<img src="'+url+'">';
console.log(document.getElementById('view').innerHtml);
```

```html
<div id=view>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `innerHTML` over DOM manipulation here. Enough to worry about allowing arbitrary URLs without introducing potential HTML injection.

Comment: Yes, that's what Anthony is suggesting. Can you provide an example for potential HTML injection in given context?

Comment: I’m saying there is no need to rely on a quirk of your input data when you can just do the right thing at no cost.

Comment: I appreciate your (and Anthony's) alternative, but I don't see any difference between your suggestion and my approach. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ek1tar8/ That's why I asked for an example. Or at least the difference between both approaches.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9ek1tar8/1/, but even if there weren’t a difference, I don’t see why you would insist on doing it the wrong way just because it happens to work for a particular type of value.

Comment: Thanks. The snippet is simplified - the whole script is a bit more complex. I need to replace all placeholders (user urls) with respective images without losing the surrounding text - I'm not sure how to push a HTMLObject into a text context. That's why I'm sticking to my approach. I'm new to JS, too, so I want to learn why something is done a certain way, not just how it is done. The answer below did rely on a malformed url which is not possible ; your comment shows some html being injected, but it can't be more harmful than any other link, no?

Comment: It may or may not be harmful. It will certainly produce an *incorrect* result. Anyway, you can just HTML-encode in that case like every decent template engine does and again not have to worry about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if the user's string is `'no" onerror="alert(0)'`?

This'll expand to:

```
<img src="http://no" onerror="alert(0)">
```

The safest way is to use `document.createElement` and assign the `src` attribute.  Using `innerHTML` isn't a very safe approach

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = ...;
```

Comment: It is a good answer and you caught me off guard there for a moment, so I thought this would be the answer. But `http://foo" onerror="alert(&apos;XSS&apos;)" "` is not a valid url, thus the payload would not be accepted as stated in question. `url` is guaranteed to be a valid url. I will emphasize that again.

Comment: How do you define a "valid url"?

Comment: HTTP valid syntax according to this rfc https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-1.1.2 for example

Comment: Could you also show us a regex, for example, of the url-validation?

Comment: AnthonySottile No, because " is not allowed and ' is reserved. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters @clabe45 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url => https://jsfiddle.net/mppkgd7u/