# Play Framework Manual Filling of Certain Fields

Tags: playframework, slick

I am using [this](https://github.com/knoldus/playing-slick-pg) to learn play-framework with `slick`.
I have this `url` form in my `controller`

```
    val urlForm = Form(
          mapping(
            "id" -> ignored(Some(0): Option[Long]),
            "link" -> nonEmptyText,
            "shortLink" -> nonEmptyText)(Url.apply)(Url.unapply))
```

On the `view` side, it is rendered as

```
@form(routes.Application.save()) {  
                    <fieldset>@formElements(urlForm)</fieldset>

                    <div class="actions">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create this url" class="btn btn-primary"> or
                        <a href="@routes.Application.list()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                    </div>          
                }
```

I have **two** questions:
**1-** How can I fill `shortLink` from data filled in `link` field and make it hidden for user.
**2-** How can I validate if data filled in `link` field is a valid `URL`

**Things I have tried:** 
**1-** Reading [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCustomValidations) and trying to use it in my project, but couldn't apply it.
**2-** Seeing answers on how to make fields hidden, but didn't work on this project because the view is just creating all the fields from `formElements(urlForm)` making me unable to set them hidden manually.

Answer (score 0):

Three things things you asked:

**Hidden Field and using the values that was passed from controller**. If you want to make it hidden in general, it relates to HTML, and you can do this in your `views` file:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="@whateverThatPassedToViews">
```

Then from this point it is all "dot notation" principle, like if you want to hide the students name and the field `fullname` is in the `Student` case class, then when you pass the list of users, you use `@student.fullname` for the value.

**How to check if the data is a valid URL**: Two ways you can do this:

1. **Pass it to the controller when the form is submitted**: Basically make it a `NonEmptyString` and pass it to the controller, and check for the validity of the URL from there.
2. **Use Javascript**: You can use Javascript, to check for the validity of the URL.

For checking the correctness of the URL, you can look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url).

Comment: All my fields are rendered through this one line `<fieldset>@formElements(urlForm)</fieldset>`, so how can I access individual fields like you told above? Like, by using dot notation? Also, as I asked, what can I do to fill the `shortLink` field from the value filled in `link` field? The transformation function for `link` to `shortLink` is in controller, but the view won't pass the form to controller unless all fields are filled.

Comment: The `@formElements.somefield` should access the field of the form. You can pass the pre calculated field (in your case `shortLink`) and pass it with the form to the views: `whatEverForm.fill(whatEverData)`. So Here you fill the form with whatever data you want to filled it in. If this is the answer, let me know, so I update the above answer.

Comment: I think I didn't quite ask my question well, how can I fill the `shortLink` field without knowing what's filled in `link` field? I can not pass `shortLink` data without knowing `link` data. I can only fill `shortLink` AFTER somehow getting the data of `link` field in controller. `shortLink` field has nothing to do with user or views, I only have to pass it to view (possibly as a hidden field) because the sql database model has a `shortLink` column which I need to fill with the processed data from `link` field. Is it making sense?