# Do I need to do anything to a Href link? Like Encoding it or so

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typescript, security, urlencode

I have a question, if I have `<a href="userInputLink" </a>` what do I need to do to the users input? I tried encoding it but then it won't work as a link.

Basically, user types some text inside a textbox and he may paste links in there too, I have a regular expression that catches user links and puts them into a href. Is this enough validation? Do I need to encode and escape characters? If yes then how? I used encodeURI and encodeURIComponent but they broke my link since you cant put that in href.

For example: User puts a message like "hey, click on this link: "https://www.youtube.com" and this link too "www.google.com" and the links get taken out from a string and put into href. Just like in any messenger where you put a link in-between a message you can click it when you send it to a different user. So do I need to encode it for security?

Here is what I have so far

[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code, not an image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40144504/2444210 Use this package to validate the URL, and reject it if it's invalid. If it's valid, use it as-is.