# Checking if a URL is valid in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http

I know questions about getting HTTP response status codes have already been asked a lot, but all the answers I've found are in jQuery. I would like this answer in pure JavaScript.

What is the simplest/best way in my script that I can receive a value for the HTTP response status code of a URL string, were the respective URL to be launched? I want my string to be checked to see if an HTTP request can be successfully completed with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a JavaScript string is a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url)

Comment: No. That question looks at the syntax of a string: I actually want my string to be checked to see if an HTTP request can be successfully completed with it.

Comment: `let response = await fetch(theURL); console.log(response.status);`

Comment: Checking the validity of the URL and checking to see if an HTTP request can be made successfully are two different things. You can have a valid url such as `https://www.thisdomaindoesnotexistasitisjustanexample.com` but an HTTP request will fail as the domain does not exist (at the time of writing!)

Comment: Alex: good point. I supposed I should have used a different word than 'valid', or at least explained better that valid meant 'currently working'.

Comment: @StephenP you should post your answer. It tested it and it works for my situation.

Comment: @StephenP suggestion works only if theUrl has the same origin or has CORS enabled. Else you a NetworkError (CORS) will be thrown.