# Fix URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

My web application has an input field where users can enter a link to their website. Usually they enter invalid URLs such as e-918kiss.com. I want to fix it to https://e-918kiss.com/ automatically.

But the URL can point to any domain name.

I tried using a tag to parse the URL, but it just appended it as the local path of the current source:

```
const elem = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'Twitter.com/mhluska';
console.log(a.href); // "http://e-918kiss.com"
```

I researched some URL parsing libraries, but they usually just throw errors for invalid URLs. Includes native URL API.

Is there an easy way to try to create a valid link from any junk that the user might enter [918kiss](https://e-918kiss.com) ?

Answer (score 0):

Regex is your friend. [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

At least minimum to know the TLD of the user domain. You can't try to guess TLD for random strings.

Then you should check if input value matches for a valid url, if not apply to the string the missing "https".

PS: domains are recommended to use SSL (https) as protocol reference but its not sure https is enabled on your users website.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/49849482/6525081
function isValidURL(string) {
  var res = string.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
  return (res !== null)
};
document.querySelector('#URL').addEventListener('change', function() {
// trigger the change event so that:
  const isUrl = isValidURL((this.value).toString()); // variable for input value
  if (isUrl !== true) { // if this is not already url,
    newVal = 'http://www.'+this.value+'.com'; // set it as url and
    this.value = newVal; // add it as the input value
  }
  else {return false} // if not abort
});
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="URL" placeholder="type string..."/>
```