# How to redirect parameter to a url?

Tags: javascript, parameters

How to redirect a parameter like ***http://example.com/?link=https://google.com*** to ***https://google.com***?

Comment: You can't do this with HTML alone. You will need javasctipt to do it client side or a server side technology of you are doing this as the result of a web request. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple way of achieving this redirect with Javascript

```js
function isValidURL(string) {
  var res = string.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
  return (res !== null)
};

var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
var redirectLink = urlParams.get('link');
if (isValidURL(redirectLink)) {
  window.location = redirectLink;
}
```

isValidURL function [author: vikasdeep-singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url)