# window.open with user input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to use the window.open command to open a new tab with the input given by the user. I'm having trouble getting it to work, Here's my code:

```js
const myButton = document.getElementById('add')
myButton.addEventListener('click', function(event2) {
  window.open('link');
})
```

```html
<input id="link" />
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct. You are trying to open 'link'. It is not even a variable, just a string.

Use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or a selector like getElementById and then get the [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue).

```
let inputVal = document.querySelector('#link').value;
//Manipulate your URL, add https:// or replace http:// with https:// or add www:



window.open(manipulatedValue);
```

Comment: When using this it opens the file location of my code and then at the end of the link the thing I put into the input box.

Comment: Nevermind this works but I have to put https://

before what i type is there anyway to make this automatic?

Comment: I have updated the answer. There can be a lot of cases, so you will have to struggle on your own for that.

Comment: @MaxSinger you should learn how javascript and the DOM api works

Answer (score 1):

This can't be really demonstrated in a stackoverflow example, due to how it's sandboxed. But you can try something like below:

```js
const link = document.getElementById("link");
const button = document.getElementById("add");
button.addEventListener("click", event => {
  const url = link.value;
  window.open(url);
});
```

Regarding the URL comment, there's no real easy way to validate if a string is a valid URL or not. Here's an answer that attempts to check that via Regular Expressions:

[Check if a JavaScript string is a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url)

Comment: Added additional information regarding URL validation. To be honest, there isn't an easy way. You'll have to set up some validation that will check the input string. I added a link from another stack overflow question that has a means to solve that with regex.