# How to enclose a user-generated URL in an `<a>` tag safely?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a community site. When a user posts a comment that contains a URL, I want to enclose that url in an `<a>` tag.

**Input**

```
Hello. Please take a look at this video.
https://example.com
```

**Output**

```
Hello. Please take a look at this video.
<a href="https://example.com">https://example.com</a>
```

**Code**

I would like to know what I should put in `regex` and `sanitizer` below.

```
const el = document.getElementById('comment')
const commentText = `Hello. Please take a look at this video.\nhttps://example.com`

el.innerHTML = commentText.replace(/regex/g, function(match){
    const sanitizedText = sanitizer(match)
    return `<a href="${sanitizedText}">${sanitizedText}</a>`
})
```

Or if there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No, the comments point out that it is unsafe.

Comment: There are 12 answers on the question. Trying to write your own sanitization routine, or outsourcing it to random people on the internet, is unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5717133/14251221), which allows both http and https protocols whilst preserving the path.

```js
var res = "https://www.google.com/search".replace(new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'), function(match){
    const sanitizedText = match.slice(8);
    return `<a href="https://${sanitizedText}">https://${sanitizedText}</a>`
})
document.write(res);
```