# How to render URLs in string as clickable hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, hyperlink, anchor

I have a `comments` (string) field from backend API which contains long text and possible with URLs too. I want to render them as hyperlinks (anchor HTML tags).

The solution I have right now, is to perform string replace using regex, to convert all URLs in the text into  tags. It's working fine.

But is there better/more holistic way to do this? Maybe some NPM package that have more features to render more than just URLs(hashtags, @user, etc)?
Btw, I'm using react/angular most of the time, any JS recommendation is applicable.

Sample data:

```
Hello, My name is John.\n\nThis is my linkedin profile: https://linkedin.com/in/john .\n\nFollow me! Thanks.
```

Expected outcome:

```
Hello, My name is John.
This is my linkedin profile: <a href="https://linkedin.com/in/john">https://linkedin.com/in/john</a> .
Follow me! Thanks.
```

Comment: There are libraries like lodash.template, handlebars, ejstemplate, vue, react. Take your pick. ejstemplate is popular for quick markup

Comment: Errr. Sorry I should make the question more clear. I'm using react. But, any JS library recommendation is good enough.

Comment: then regex is probably the right way to do it, since you have to extract the url from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working JS (typescript) function to perform string replace URL to `<a>` tag.

```
const Regex_Url_Str = "(https?:\\/\\/)?" // protocol
+ "((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|" // domain name
+ "((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))" // OR ip (v4) address
+ "(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*" // port and path
+ "(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?" // query string
+ "(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?";

const StringUtil = {
  isValidUrl: (str: string): boolean => new RegExp(Regex_Url_Str, "i").test(str),
  parseHyperlinks: (str: string): string => str.replaceAll(new RegExp(Regex_Url_Str, "gim"), "<a target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noreferrer\" href=\"$&\">$&</a>"),
};

export default StringUtil;
```

```
import StringUtil from "../utils/string.ts";

const str = "your_text";
const parsed = StringUtil.parseHyperlinks(str);
```

The regex is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5717133/6122411