# How to accept port number in this regex?

Tags: regex

This is url validation regex

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

This works Okay.
However if I type url with port number such as **http://localhost:3000**, it gives an error.

How can I change this expression to accept a port number as well?

Comment: I don't think there's anything in the original regexp that's specific to PHP. It should work as is.

Comment: Why do you think `http`  by itself should match? If you want to match a URL, you need more than just the protocol name.

Comment: Can you post the exact PHP code that prints true for `"http"`? From a quick glance, the `.` in this regex looks to be a required character.

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` inside `[]` in either language.

Comment: But you need to escape `/` inside `[]`.

Comment: Can you give examples of URLs you wish to validate?

Comment: @Barmar isn't 'https?' makes 's' optional?

Comment: @nice_dev such as 'http://localhost:3000'

Comment: @GoonGamja Yes. But nothing makes the rest of the URL optional. It needs to be something like `http://foo.bar.com/x/y/z`

Comment: Your PHP regexp works with JS: https://regex101.com/r/a4RtLl/1

Comment: my bad! http works just fine. the problem was port number

Comment: @GoonGamja Don't use regex to validate URL. There are better ways. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url

Comment: Why is this tagged with JS and PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: @NicoHaase when I edit my question, forgot to remove the tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please can try this one

`https?:\/\/(?:w{1,3}\.)?[^\s.]+(?:\.[a-z]+)*(?::\d+)?(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))`

`https?`: This part matches the protocol of the URL. The s is optional, so it matches both http and https.

`:\/\/`: This matches the colon and two forward slashes that are part of the protocol.

`(?:w{1,3}\.)?`: This matches the optional www subdomain, if it exists. The (?: ) creates a non-capturing group, and the {1,3} quantifier matches between 1 and 3 instances of the letter "w".

`[^\s.]+`: This matches the domain name, which consists of one or more characters that are not whitespace or a dot.

`(?:\.[a-z]+)*`: This matches any optional subdomains that come before the domain, separated by dots. The (?: ) creates another non-capturing group, and the * quantifier matches zero or more instances of this group. The [a-z]+ matches one or more lowercase letters.

`(?::\d+)?`: This matches an optional port number that might come after the domain, preceded by a colon. The (?: ) creates another non-capturing group, and the ? quantifier makes it optional. The : matches the colon, and \d+ matches one or more digits.

`(?![^<]*(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>))`: This is a negative lookahead that ensures that the URL is not part of an HTML tag. It checks if there are no characters before the URL that match the pattern `(?:<\/\w+>|\/?>)`, which matches any closing HTML tag or an empty tag.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?