# How to Parse Text Responses to Create Hyperlinks and Highlight Certain Texts in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently working on a React project and I've encountered a challenge.
I have a text response that I need to parse in such a way that any URLs in the text are converted to clickable hyperlinks ( tags).
Additionally, I have a requirement where I need to highlight certain words within the text based on a provided search value.

This highlighted text isn't part of the URL, it could be anywhere within the text response.

For example, given this text:
"Hello, check out https://www.example.com for more details. The example site is really useful."

If my search value was "example", I'd want to generate:

```
<span>
  Hello, check out <a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">https://www.example.com</a> for more 
  details. The <mark>example</mark> site is really useful.
</span>
```

Where "https://www.example.com" is a clickable hyperlink and "example" is highlighted.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this in React would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your sentence on a space, then [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over them;

- If it matches your search pattern, wrap it in `<mark>`.
- If it matches an url, wrap it in a `<a>`.
  I've used the regex to check for an url from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url/5717133#5717133).

Then return the element, with a space at the end if it's not the last word.

The reason why we apply the space manually is because [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) can't be  used with an array holding React elements.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const validURL = (str) => {
        var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
        '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
        '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
        '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
        '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
        '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
        return !!pattern.test(str);
    }

    const search = "example";
    const raw = "Hello, check out https://www.example.com for more details. The example site is really useful.";
    const splitted = raw.split(' ');
    
    const parsed = splitted.map((p, i) => {
        let e = p;
        if (p === search) {
            e = <mark>{p}</mark>
        } else if (validURL(p)) {
            e = <a href={p} target="_blank">{p}</a>;
        }
        return <React.Fragment>{e}{(i === splitted.length) ? '' : ' '}</React.Fragment>;
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <em>{parsed}</em>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I want to highlight https in a-link when I search for https , what adjustments should I make?